# Add compile warnings to C# method

Tags: c#, console, cross-platform

When calling the `Console.SetWindowSize`, I get a nice warning telling about OS support:

```cs
Console.SetWindowSize(width, height); // Warning:
```

> This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Console.SetWindowSize(int, int)' is only supported on: 'windows'. csharp(CA1416)

If I wrap this in an OS check, the warning goes away:

```cs
if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
    Console.SetWindowSize(width, height); // No warnings
}
```

#### Question

Is it possible to decorate a custom method so that it behaves in a similar manner, giving a warning when not wrapped in a check for OS?

I've had a look at the [source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/console.cs) (I think this is the source, anyway), and I cant see anything on the `Console.SetWindowSize` method that would cause this warning, so I'm not sure how it works, and thus not sure how I could leverage it in my own methods (or whether it's even possible).

#### Pseudo Example

A naive pseudo example of what I'd like to try and achieve.

```cs
[SupportedOperatingSystem(OS.Windows)]
public void MyWindowsOnlyMethod()
{
}

if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
    MyWindowsOnlyMethod(); // No warning
}
else
{
    MyWindowsOnlyMethod(); // Warning
}
```

#### Environment

Since I'm not totally sure what generates these warning, it's worth mentioning my setup:

- C# 11
- .Net 7
- VSCode (C# extension)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is almost exactly what I was hoping to do:

Use the [`SupportedOSPlatform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.versioning.supportedosplatformattribute?view=net-7.0) attribute. E.g.

```cs
[System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public void MyWindowsOnlyMethod()
{
}

if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
{
    MyWindowsOnlyMethod(); // No warning
}
else
{
    MyWindowsOnlyMethod(); // Warning
}
`
```

Comment: Actually you can specify the platform in the .csproj file by adding `-windows` to the target framework `<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>`. This has a global effect.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks, that's good to know! I guess if you want your project to support multiple operating systems, but certain functions only to support specific operating systems, it seems like `SupportedOSPlatformAttribute` is the way to go.